# Django BeautifulSoup FeatureNotFound

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

When trying to scrape something with BeautifulSoup with Django it returns:

```
 Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html,fast. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

The line of code that it is stopping at is:

```
urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()    
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(urlContent))
```

I've tried different ways to import:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import BeautifulSoup
etc, etc.
```

I'm at a stump, I don't know what's casing this or why. Works fine when testing it in a .py so I can only assume it's Django. Any known fixes/work around?

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\django\bin\project\Main\functions.py" in mangasee
  44.   soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(urlContent))
File "D:\django\bin\project\Main\bs4\__init__.py" in __init__
  152.                     % ",".join(features))

Exception Type: FeatureNotFound at /moderator/
Exception Value: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html,fast. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Comment: Please show the complete traceback and the line where error occurs. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Added what was in it

Comment: Does installing `html5lib` help? (`pip install html5lib`)

Comment: @alecxe Installed, didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite clear from the error information that Python cannot find an HTML parser, which is required for the bs to work. BeautifulSoup supports a number of parsers such as the HTML parser in Python's standard library. From the code you've provided I cannot see why a parser was not found. Sometimes it's because the version of bs does not match the version of Python you're using. Please see this site http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup for more information.

Comment: Although I'm running python 2.7 it seems that django is only accepting BS3. Thank you for the documents!